Extending wordpress adding extra path information to a page URL
I have a page with a URL like http://example.com/pagename?query=foo.
I can get that query=foo data using the get_query_var method.
But for convenience, I need to replace it with something like http://example.com/pagename/foo
To make it work, I must convince WordPress that pagename/foo is pagename with extra information.
But I can't find a way to do that.
I looked up the Wordpress documentation and googled for it, but I am unable to use the proper words to find a solution, or there is none, as I can't find anything.

You need to use add_rewrite_rule. The first parameter is probably pagename/foo and the second parameter is index.php?name=pagename&query=foo. If you have multiple of these, or need it to be dynamic, there's ways of doing that, too.

Thanks, will give it a try. I am also trying to look into the possibility of using nginx to do that job.

I would strongly recommend avoiding configuring this at the server level. These kinds of configs are not that portable, so you can't test locally easily without mirroring the server, and they will be forgotten about if/when you change servers in the future. Further, once you add any feature it tends to grow, so now you'll be managing things in multiple places. Let your server serve files, and route 404's to WordPress to figure out what to do with the rest, and your life will generally be easier.

I am getting it to work with add_rewrite_rule. My only problem is that the query is being double utf-8 encoded...

This is an answer based on Chris Haas comment.
I used this code snippet to do the rewrite of pesquisa/?word=something to index.php?pagename=pesquisa&word=something:
function gp_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^pesquisa/([^/]+)/?',
                   'index.php?pagename=pesquisa&word=$matches[1]', 'top');  
}

In order for this function to evaluate, I needed this:
add_action( 'init', 'gp_rewrite' );

I also needed to declare the query variable:
function dacl_register_query_var( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'word';
    return $qvars;
}

Finally, my search function does this:
function dacl_search_word() {
    
    $query = rawurldecode(get_query_var("word"));
    ...

Note the rawurldecode, otherwise I got utf8 characters double encoded.
Finally, do not forget to go to the Settings -> Permanent Links page in your Wordpress installation and hit save, to force the permanent link cache to be updated.
